# Oracle SQL Query to get min and min date based the records

Tags: sql

input:

```
date1, id, device1, device2
1jul,  1, enable, disable
2jul, 1, enable , disable
3jul, 1, enable, disable
4jul, 1, unknown, enable
5jul, 1, enable, disable
6jul, 1, enable, disable
```

how to get below outptut:

```
id, device1,device2, mindate, maxdate
1, enable, disable, 1jul, 3jul
1, unknown, enable, 4jul, 4jul
1, enable, disable, 5th, 6th
```

Comment: Did you mean MIN and MAX date?

Comment: 1jul,  1, enable, disable
2jul, 1, enable , disable
3jul, 1, enable, disable, for these three records all other details are same except date1. so one record should be created like below            id, device1,device2, mindate, maxdate
1, enable, disable, 1jul, 3jul

Comment: for 4th record in in the input list, there is an unknown in device, we cannot find anycombination with that so it should have min and max as same date as 4th july

Comment: i tried with lag and lead, but for 1,2,3,5,6 will be grouped together

Comment: but since 4th record is having device1 as different value first 3 should be grouped togehr, 4th as unique one, and 5th and 6 should be grouped together

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  In this case, the difference of row numbers is probably the simplest solution:

```
select id, device1, device2, min(date1), max(date1)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, device1, device2 order by date1) as seqnum_2,
             row_number() over (partition by idorder by date1) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id, device1, device2, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
```